# Differentiation in python using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, differentiation

How do i implement this kind of equation in python dC/dt = r + kI - dC where the left hand side are constants and the right hand side are varibles?

i am relatively new to python and as such can't really do much.
`from sympy.solvers import ode`

`r=float(input("enter r:"))`

`k=float(input("enter k:"))`

`I=float(input("enter I:"))`

`d=float(input("enter d:"))`

`C=float(input("enter C:"))`

`dC/dt=x`

`x=r + kI-dC`

`print(x)`

what it just does equate the values of x and not any differential, would like help getting this to work.

if possible i would like to get answer specifying the using of sympy,
but all answers are truly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/differentiation.html)

Comment: yh i have thank you, but i didn't really get it that's why i put up that equation in the question so if i am able to get the answer i can review it to know how its done.

Comment: @KennethIwuchukwu It seems that you could profit going through [the Sympy Tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html). Later you should study [this section](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html#solving-differential-equations) in particular.

Comment: thank you @gboffi will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asigned values to all the variables that are on the rhs of x so when you show x you see the value that it took on with the variables that you defined. Rather than input values, why not try solve the ode symbolically if possible?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('r k I d C t')
(r, k, I, d, C, t)
>>> eq = Eq(C(t).diff(t), r + k*I + d*C(t))  # note d*C(t) not d*C
>>> ans = dsolve(eq); ans
C(t) == (-I*k - r + exp(d*(C1 + t)))/d
```

Now you can substitute in values for the variables to see the result:

```
>>> ans.subs({k: 0})
C(t) == (-r + exp(d*(C1 + t)))/d
```

Comment: thanks for your input but i tried run the code and it came back with this error "NameError: name 'C1' is not defined" thats before & after i replace the variables i replace the variables also is it necessary to factor the c on the right hand side to (t) - its a variable. if i replace the variables in the last equation line C(t)==.... it returns this "Process finished with exit code 0" thanks

Comment: how bout if i but the equation this way `dr/dt= r + k.I - d.p` thanks

Comment: It's not necessary to make the C on the rhs a function of t; but then you should use a different symbol since C on the left must be a function of t or else dC/dt is 0. For the other equation, the approach is the same: eq = Eq(r(t).diff(t), r0 + k*I + d*p. Note that you have the same question about r on the lhs and rhs: do you mean a constant on the right (like r0) or do you mean r(t)?

Comment: thank you so much, saw my mistake- code is perfect > but when i substitute the variables i get this output eq = Eq(X(t).diff(t), r + k*I + d*C(t)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: also @smichr aside from solving it symbolically is there any other way (examples would be helpful)

Comment: You get that error because before you typed `eq = ...` you must have made C = 42 (or some other number). So you have to decide if a) C(t) is a function and will be part of the equation in which dC(t)/dt is defined or b) a constant that you want to be able to specify.

Comment: > is there any other way  {Any other way to do what?}